# Validating the Presence of an ActiveRecord Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

Is there a way I can validate from within a method that it's running with an active Transaction block?  Basically we have library methods that do a few ActiveRecord save operations that should be run within a Transaction block (so that everything is rolled back if any operation fails), and some of the users consuming our library are not wrapping these methods in transactions as documented.

I was hoping there was some sort of helper method I could write like `withinTransactionBlock?` that would verify an ActiveRecord transaction and raise an exception if it returns false.

If this is currently impossible, how might I begin writing such a method that ensures several methods in my library are run in an atomic fashion (aside from packaging every permutation of the methods sequenced into separate functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check is any transaction opened with

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check_transaction
    p self.class.connection.transaction_open?
  end
end

User.new.check_transaction
# false

User.transaction do
  User.new.check_transaction
end  
# true
```

And even if transaction is opened on another AR subclass

```
Account.transaction do
  User.new.check_transaction  
end  
# true
```